# jQuery return undefined JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a button that post to the server. This works fine taking two parameters to perform a query that returns `JSON` objects. I want to asynchronously update the webpage with some of the returned `JSON` data immediately the button is clicked. I have this code that return undefined or just the last value out of all the `JSON` objects. I don't know what I am doing wrong, can someone kindly point me in the right direction?

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    $.post('search.php', {
            regNo: $("#regNo").val(),
            datepicker: $(".datepicker").text()
        },
        function(data) {
            var obj = data.valueOf();

            $.each(obj, function(i) {
                $('#responsetxt').html("<b>"+obj[i].time+ "</b>");
            });
        },
        'json');
    });
});
```

Comment: You sure you are getting the data you want from search.php? Include the content of search.php if you can.

Comment: Why are you doing `var obj = data.valueOf()`? Just use `data`.

Comment: `{"id":"10","regNo":"357139052579492","timezone":"0","time":"1393344365", "reason":"3"}` -Sample of returned JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the ugly index `data[i].time` to simply `data.time` .

```
` $('#mybutton').click(function() {
$.post('search.php', {
        regNo: $("#regNo").val(),
        datepicker: $(".datepicker").text()
    },
    function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i) {
            $('#responsetxt').html("<b>"+data.time+ "</b>");
        });
    },
    'json');
});});`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `undefined`, then there's most likely a problem with the data you have sent, or there are no matches.

As for "getting only the last one", well... in your `.each` you are repeatedly overwriting the `#responsetxt` contents, so... it should be no surprise that only the last one is left. Instead, consider building a string and then calling `.html()` *after* the loop with the constructed string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
$.post('search.php', {
        regNo: $("#regNo").val(),
        datepicker: $(".datepicker").text()
    },
    function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i) {
            $('#responsetxt').html("<b>"+data[i].time+ "</b>");
        });
    },
    'json');
});});
```

Comment: Thanks Eshan, tried it it still returned undefined and withouth `.time` it returned the last value.

Comment: Then have a look at Niet's answer. You are getting "undefined" because you don't have data. and you are getting the last one because you keep overwriting the value of $('#responsetxt') in each loop. try `alert(obj[i].time)` in your loop instead and see if you can alert time of all the objects or still the last one.